# ZVS troubleshooting waveform

Tags: zvs

I have been running various different ZVS based flybacks for all kinds of uses (jacobs ladders, SSTCs, etc.), however, for some reason, I am now getting mosfet heating, which was never apparent before – so I am unsure as to why no matter what I do, I have this issue now.

With a simple induction coil as load, I used to be able to run indefinitely with 300W, and with watercooling (as opposed to a small heatsink and fan) up to around 900W comfortably.

Now, it seems, I struggle to manage the MOSFET heating at anything over 100W sustained, which results in mosfets that were previously cool to the touch, sitting at 65C even at 100W (6A average load).

I have changed FETS, caps, coils, made new PCBs and played with designs, but I seem limited. I have years of experience with these kinds of circuits but now I am stumped. The waveform presents a perfect sine from the two sides, but probing each side shows strange oscillations that I assume to be switching artifacts.

View a diagram / schematic of the type of circuit here:
https://cdn.instructables.com/F7Y/CH9S/G9NH8XOF/F7YCH9SG9NH8XOF.MEDIUM.jpg

[image]

And a video of the waveform here as I change V and I (which upsets my power supply occasionally):
https://youtu.be/vacUYmgCReA

The DC supply is a 900w 30V/30A switching bench supply, so should be up to the job.

I believe the spurious oscillations are due to switching problems. All my components are new and I still get the issue, I only built this to test what was going on and it still happens :-/

Any advice would be most welcome... I simply can't see how or why it's heating up and killing fets, and I am pulling my hair out after building several of these with new components after having built a few dozen years back without any issues.

Comment: The negative half sines change on the negative leading edge , indicating it is not gating symmetrically.  ( possible cross-conduction)  For debugging add 0.01 Ohm now   current sense and use proper probing methods ( very short leads or dual pins for sig+gnd on 10:1 probe.

Comment: Thanks Tony, will endeavor to look at this tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: or.. using two probes in A-B mode verified to flat line on same signal... then measure Vds then Vgs.  The 1st explanation for hot FETs is Ohm's Law and the results of VI product.  Then look at load reactance vs Vgs

Comment: I think I will have to use A-B mode. Thanks again...

Comment: Hi Tony,

Did as you suggested and confirmed cross conduction as you suggested, thank you. Seems that some strange effects are occurring which means that I seem to need in my case to reduce the value of the gate resistors. However now I noticed oscillations from the gate switching, which I will have to address.

Comment: Keep probe gnd short ( < 1cm ) with twin wire to tip and barrel with clip removed.  and increase dead-time> 0.5us. The low C ultrafast diodes must turn Off FET faster than RC turn On to achieve this. Poor choices lead to cross-conduction.

Comment: Hi Tony, you have been a great help, thank you. Now I have these parasitics to deal with, but the fets stay under 40C with some very minor cooling. 
I would like to address these from a noise and making it better / educational perspective: https://youtu.be/2rTkv9IZOao 

This appears from probing to be caused by the gate oscillating. I am using 35nS diodes, so they are definitely fast enough, capacitance appears to be tiny with these ones. I attempted to use a high voltage schotty to reduce the time further but the high C caused it to fail to oscillate (as I expected, but attempted anyway)

Comment: Sorry - in A+B mode (If I probe the gates I see these parasitics too, the power supply is separate for the gate drive): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NuCtp2GMa9o

Comment: BTW, I have also attempted adding a 2uH inductor between the gate and the circuit, and it made the issue worse - so wonder if inductance is the cause. Strange as very little has changed since it worked better than currently, and all components have been swapped for new items to try to eliminate a bad component.

Comment: Since Gate Ciss reacts with inductance use low ESL and feed impedance match if possible. Load impedance is ?
... probes should be A-B

Comment: First video is A-B, I can make another.
Load impedance is around 2uH and measured by LCR meter. Changing load does little, but if I place extra load (i.e. screwdriver within coil, situation is a little improved. All capacitors on the load are low ESL quality MKP. Impedence of supply has been reduced as much as possible and large (68000uF) capacitance on the supply side (for the load not gates) placed within inches of the PCB, run from PCB to center of coil is around 4 inches / 100mm

Comment: The impedance of an arc is inverse with current density and also negative ESR. so spurious reflections in mismatch are normal.

Comment: I'm not drawing an arc, I am powering a simple induction coil as a test load. Any ideas? Once its running reliably I will migrate it back to a jacobs ladder.

Comment: Try a light bulb